# Without computing it, conclude that $\tan(\frac{\pi}{8})$ is irrational.

Tags: irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

Let $ \theta\in (0,\frac{\pi}{4})$.

Prove that
$$ \sqrt{\sin(4\theta)}\in \Bbb Q \implies \tan(\theta)\notin \Bbb Q$$
and conclude that $\tan(\frac{\pi}{8})\notin \Bbb Q$.
I tried the contrapositve, but it became more difficult.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The contrapositive does seem to look promising: By complex numbers we have $\sin 4\theta = \frac{4\tan\theta(1-\tan^2\theta)}{(1+\tan^2\theta)^2}$ in the given interval. If we plug $\tan\theta=p/q$ into this and remove obviously square factors, this means we'd need to prove that $pq(q^2-p^2)$ is never a perfect square when $p$ and $q$ are distinct integers.

Comment: This is a PSQ, @hamam, and you know what a PSQ is because you frequently answer them. At your rep, you have no excuse for not providing more context.  Particular when users with less 1/100th of you rep answer it???

Comment: Ok, i closed it. You can delete it .

Comment: You can note that if $x=\tan(\pi/8)$ then $1=\tan(\pi/4)=2x/(1-x^2)$ ie $x^2+2x-1=0$ which has no rational roots

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $\tan\theta$ is rational with $0<\theta<\pi/4$, and that $\sin 4\theta$ is the square of a rational number. We're aiming for a contradiction.

Let $t=\tan\theta$. Then the complex number $1+it$ has argument $\theta$, and so $(1+it)^4$ has argument $4\theta$. Thus,
$$ \sin 4\theta = \frac{\mathop{\mathrm{Im}}\,(1+it)^4}{|(1+it)^4|} = \frac{4t(1-t^2)}{(1+t^2)^2}$$

Now suppose $t=p/q$ in lowest terms. Plugging in, we find
$$ \sin 4\theta = \frac{4p(1-p^2/q^2)}{q(1+p^2/q^2)^2} = \Bigl(\frac{2}{q^2(1+p^2/q^2)}\Bigr)^2 pq(q^2-p^2) $$

Thus, $pq(q^2-p^2)$ needs to be a perfect square.

However, since $p$ and $q$ are assumed coprime, no prime factor in $p$ appears in either $q$ or $q^2-p^2$, so $p$ itself has to be a square. Similarly $q$ has to be a square. Thus the third factor $q^2-p^2$ has to be square too.

So we have $p=x^2$, $q=z^2$, where $x$ and $z$ need to belong to a solution of
$$ x^4 + y^2 = z^4 $$
But [Fermat's right triangle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_right_triangle_theorem) tells us that this has no nontrivial solutions. (The trivial solution $y=0$ corresponds to $p=q$ and thus $\theta=\pi/4$, and $x=0$ corresponds to $\theta=0$, which are both out of the explicitly assumed range).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The typical proof of something like this is sometimes called "infinite descent" - you show that any solution would imply a smaller solution, which would imply a smaller solution... Since you're working with positive integers, there's only so far you could descend, so you get a contradiction.

So assume $\sqrt{3}=\frac{p}{q}$ where $p$ and $q$ have no common factors. Then we have $3=\frac{p^2}{q^2}$ or $3p^{2}=q^{2}$. But 3 is prime and divides the left hand side. So it also divides the right hand side. Since 3 divides $q^{2}$ it has to divide $q$. Say, $q=3q'$. Then we have $3p^{2}=9(q')^{2]}$. Dividing both sides by 3, we now have $p^{2}=3(q')^{2}$, so by the same argument $p = 3p'$  for some integer $p'$. This gives us a smaller pair of integers $p', q'$ such that $\sqrt{3}=\frac{p'}{q'}$, which gives us the start of our infinite descent. (Or, more simply, we've contradicted the initial premise that $p$ and $q$ have no common factor.)

Note this says $\sqrt{n}$ is irrational for **any** positive prime number $n$.

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the trigonometric implication in the question body.

Comment: Thanks for the time you took. (+1).

Comment: (When this answer was posted, the question looked like it was asking for a proof that $\sqrt 3$ is irrational -- it was later edited to remove that connection).

Comment: Good point.  This isn't a shooting gallery.

Comment: How do you show that $pq (q^2 - p^2)$ is never a perfect square, when $p,q$ are distinct integers?